# NullPointerException error in grails

Tags: java, grails, nullpointerexception

I'm really getting mad with this.

My goal is to save in which state/region an object is, so I set up this domain class:

```
class State {

    String stateName
    String stateIsoCode

    static hasMany = [regions: Region]

    static constraints = {
        stateIsoCode unique:true
        stateName unique:true
    }
}


class Region {

    String regionName
    String regionIsoCode

    static belongsTo = [state: State]
    static hasMany = [provinces: Province]

    static constraints = {
        regionIsoCode unique:true
        regionName unique:true
    }
}
```

when someone want to insert the location of his object he can do it with a select which have as value the isoCode of the state or region

so in the controller I try to set the location of the object in this way:

```
materialInstance.state = State.findByStateIsoCode(params?.state)
materialInstance.region = Region.findByRegionIsoCodeAndState(params.region,materialInstance.state)
```

And I get this error:

```
| Error 2015-01-17 19:04:19,923 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing...
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>  163 | removeBatchLoadableEntityKey    in org.hibernate.engine.spi.BatchFetchQueue
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    388 | addEntity                       in org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext
|    461 | addEntity . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    143 | makeEntityManaged               in org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction
|    201 | addResolvedEntityInsertAction . in org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue
|    179 | addInsertAction                 in     ''
|    214 | addAction . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    324 | addInsertAction                 in org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener
|    288 | performSaveOrReplicate . . . .  in     ''
|    194 | performSave                     in     ''
|    125 | saveWithGeneratedId . . . . . . in     ''
|    209 | saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId  in org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener
|    194 | entityIsTransient . . . . . . . in     ''
|    114 | performSaveOrUpdate             in     ''
|     90 | onSaveOrUpdate . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    684 | fireSaveOrUpdate                in org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl
|    676 | saveOrUpdate . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    235 | cascade                         in org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5
|    350 | cascadeToOne . . . . . . . . .  in org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade
|    293 | cascadeAssociation              in     ''
|    161 | cascadeProperty . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    379 | cascadeCollectionElements       in     ''
|    319 | cascadeCollection . . . . . . . in     ''
|    296 | cascadeAssociation              in     ''
|    161 | cascadeProperty . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    118 | cascade                         in     ''
|    167 | cascadeOnFlush . . . . . . . .  in org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener
|    158 | prepareEntityFlushes            in     ''
|     91 | flushEverythingToExecutions . . in     ''
|     61 | onAutoFlush                     in org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener
|   1191 | autoFlushIfRequired . . . . . . in org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl
|   1675 | list                            in     ''
|    380 | list . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl
|    105 | getResult                       in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractFindByPersistentMethod
|     67 | doInHibernate . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractFindByPersistentMethod$1
|    179 | doExecute                       in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate
|    123 | execute . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|     62 | doInvokeInternalWithExpressions in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractFindByPersistentMethod
|    544 | doInvokeInternal . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod
|    418 | doInvokeInternal                in     ''
|     79 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod
|     72 | invoke                          in     ''
|     -1 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.metaclass.StaticMethodInvocation$invoke$0
|     45 | defaultCall                     in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray
|     -1 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.metaclass.StaticMethodInvocation$invoke$0
|    102 | doCall                          in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2
|     -1 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     59 | invoke                          in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureStaticMetaMethod
|    324 | doMethodInvoke . . . . . . . .  in groovy.lang.MetaMethod
|     43 | invoke                          in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite
|     88 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    116 | call                            in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite
|     46 | $tt__save . . . . . . . . . . . in com.circularMaterial.core.MaterialController$$EP1eJsbQ
|     -1 | $tt__save                       in com.circularMaterial.core.MaterialController$$DP1eJsbQ
|     -2 | invoke0 . . . . . . . . . . . . in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
|     62 | invoke                          in     ''
|     43 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
|    483 | invoke                          in java.lang.reflect.Method
|    122 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2
|   1299 | jlrMethodInvoke                 in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
|     90 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod
|    324 | doMethodInvoke                  in groovy.lang.MetaMethod
|   1207 | invokeMethod . . . . . . . . .  in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
|   1110 | invokeMethod                    in groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass
|   1016 | invokeMethod . . . . . . . . .  in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
|    423 | call                            in groovy.lang.Closure
|     -1 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.circularMaterial.core.MaterialController$_save_closure4
|    439 | call                            in groovy.lang.Closure
|     -1 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.circularMaterial.core.MaterialController$_save_closure4
|     88 | doInTransaction                 in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2
|    133 | execute . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate
|     85 | execute                         in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate
|     -1 | save . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.circularMaterial.core.MaterialController$$EP1eJsbQ
|     -2 | invoke0                         in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
|     62 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     43 | invoke                          in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
|    483 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.reflect.Method
|    122 | invoke                          in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2
|   1299 | jlrMethodInvoke . . . . . . . . in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
|    154 | invoke                          in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper
|    375 | handleAction . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper
|    252 | executeAction                   in     ''
|    205 | handleURI . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    126 | handleURI                       in     ''
|     72 | handleRequest . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController
|     50 | handle                          in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter
|    347 | doDispatch . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet
|    870 | doService                       in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
|    961 | processRequest . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    863 | doPost                          in     ''
|    646 | service . . . . . . . . . . . . in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
|    837 | service                         in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    727 | service . . . . . . . . . . . . in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
|    303 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     52 | doFilter                        in org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    198 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter                        in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    344 | invokeDelegate . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    261 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    101 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    101 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    101 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    748 | invoke                          in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
|    486 | processRequest . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    411 | doForward                       in     ''
|    338 | forward . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    178 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils
|    144 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo in     ''
|    135 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo in     ''
|    216 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter
|    107 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    330 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    118 | invoke                          in org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
|     84 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    342 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    113 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter
|    342 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     53 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    342 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    146 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
|    342 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    154 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
|    342 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    199 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
|     49 | doFilter                        in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|    342 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     82 | doFilter                        in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|    342 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     87 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
|    342 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    192 | doFilterInternal                in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
|    160 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    344 | invokeDelegate                  in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    261 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    241 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     69 | doFilterInternal                in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter
|    107 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     67 | doFilterInternal                in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
|    107 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     88 | doFilterInternal                in org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
|    107 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    344 | invokeDelegate                  in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    261 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    241 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    220 | invoke                          in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
|    122 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve
|    171 | invoke                          in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve
|    103 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve
|    116 | invoke                          in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve
|    408 | service . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter
|   1070 | process                         in org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor
|    611 | process . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler
|    316 | run                             in org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor
|   1142 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run                             in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|     61 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable
^    745 | run                             in java.lang.Thread
```

I can't understand what causes it, overmore if I comment the peice of code which save the state and the region, I go through the controller (and I get the error because they are not nullable field) and then I uncomment it , it works.

I am using grails whit a nosql database and I am working on the debug enviroment

Thank you

Comment: are all of your parameters to the queries are not null?

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor yes, both of them aren't null

Comment: why do you have state and region field in location? state and region are related. So having 'region' field is enough.

Comment: the exception says, that `  194 | performSave` so the problem must be somewhere else, when you are trying to call `save()`

Comment: @Simo Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: @XDR Well, I've moved the piece of code which caused me the problem in another point of the controller and it didn't give me the error anymore, but this isn't a really solution, I still don't know why it gave to me this error and how to really solve it.

Comment: I eventually found a solution to my problem; a date string format used by the JSON wasn't in the grails.databinding.dateFormats list, so I added it.  It took tons of debugging of Grails & GORM to figure this out, since the date format error was never output, but it caused GORM to do something different that caused this subsequent NPE much later in the runtime.

Comment: @Simo I have similar domain relationship as you have and even I am facing the same issue, all params to dynamic finder are not null, but still i get null pointer exception, without showing what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caused by underlying Hibernate issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11721